# Python JSON cant pull out and print textual identifier

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to pull out and print the place ID from this
http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson

Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import json

serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + '?' + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address':  address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

    try: 
        js = json.loads(str(data))
    except: 
        js = None
        if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
            print '==== Failure To Retrieve ===='
            print data
            continue
    print json.dumps(js, indent=4)
    placeid = js['results'][0]['place_id']

    print "Place ID: ", placeid
    print placeid
    print location
```

The output im getting is correct, but the place ID is not being printed. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: I just tested this, and the `placeid` is getting printed just fine when I use one of the values in the link provided, but `location` is undefined.

Comment: I'm able to get the place id, just that your code got an error. NameError: name 'location' is not defined

Comment: @jYeager  what test value did you use? It's weird I cannot get any placeid's to print.

Comment: @skycrew  I removed the location stuff, sorry about that.

Comment: @Oscalation `RPI` and `BITS Pilani` both work for me.

Comment: Oscalation, ... what do you put in? I used "UCLA" and got the ID. If you enter an unknown name, you get a list of valid names and your code skips printing ID.

Comment: This part `if 'status' not in js...` causes you to skip getting the ID because you get a list of possible locations instead of a dict of one location, `"status"` is not in the location list so you skip it. How about checking whether you you got a list or a dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as noted in the comments - it works if you change your variable name:

```
import urllib
import json

serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + '?' + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address':  address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

    try: js = json.loads(str(data))
    except: js = None
    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
        print '==== Failure To Retrieve ===='
        print data
        continue
    #print json.dumps(js, indent=4) # commented out to stop filling my screen with place names - easily put back in
    placeid = js['results'][0]['place_id']

    print "Place ID: ", placeid
    print placeid
    print address    # location not defined
```

The important bit is that last line, which changes the variable name to be the one you declared in the request for user input.

I used 'University of Toronto' as a test, without problems.

Comment: Oh i see now, I originally declared it as 'address'. Thank you for clarifying this so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't check whether the user's location was recognized by the system. When you enter a bad location, you get an error key and a list of valid locations. Just check for that.

```
import urllib
import json

serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + '?' + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address':  address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    # uncomment for debug...
    #print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

    try: 
        js = json.loads(str(data))
    except:
        js = None
        print 'got exception'
        continue

    if "error" in js:
        print "Choose a location from the following list"
        for location in js["locations"]:
            print '   ', location
        continue

    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
        print '==== Failure To Retrieve ===='
        print data
        continue
    print json.dumps(js, indent=4)
    placeid = js['results'][0]['place_id']

    print "Place ID: ", placeid
    print placeid
```